# Firebase cloud function with AppCheck failing with 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I just deployed my first flutter web app with a Firebase cloud function called "createCompany".  The function works fine when running against the Firebase emulators, but fails with an (unhelpful) error when deployed live:

Cloud console error log:

> 2023-04-29 12:32:42.138 MST createCompany 17d1f7wc8kv1 Function
> execution started
>
> 2023-04-29 12:32:42.144 MST createCompany 17d1f7wc8kv1 Callable
> request verification passed
>
> 2023-04-29 12:32:42.145 MST createCompany 17d1f7wc8kv1 Function
> execution took 7ms, finished with status: 'error'

The Chrome developer console's Network Monitor shows an invocation of createCompany with a response of 401 - Unauthorized.

I set up AppCheck and this appears to be the source of the problem.  When I redeploy after removing enforceAppCheck from the cloud function, it runs successfully.

Setup in main:

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  AndroidProvider provider = AndroidProvider.playIntegrity;
  if (kDebugMode) {
    provider = AndroidProvider.debug;
  }
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: '<My actual site key here>',
    androidProvider: provider,
  );
```

Invocation in flutter

```
Future<String> createCompany(String firstName, String lastName) async {
        var result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance
            .httpsCallable('createCompany')
            .call(<String, dynamic>{'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName});
        return result.data["company"];
      }
```

Cloud function:

```
     exports.createCompany = functions.runWith({
          enforceAppCheck: true
        })
          .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        
            functions.logger.log("createCompany start");
        
            if (context.app == undefined) {
              throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                'failed-precondition',
                'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.')
            }
... //Function logic
```

Cloud console settings for invoker:

[image: Cloud console settings]

My reCAPTCHA secret key has been entered in the Firebase console.

What else do I need to do to make this work in production?

Comment: Have you added SHA fingerprints in Firebase / Google Cloud Console? This problem occurs on both Android and iOS?

Comment: I'm not able to try iOS or Android outside a debug environment so I'm not sure if it occurs there.  Is there anywhere I need to add a SHA fingerprint aside from the ones under the AppCheck tab on the Firebase console?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you have a web application. In this case in the Firebase Console, under AppCheck / Apps, have you added your web application? If yes, have you added your reCAPTCHA secret key?

Comment: Yes the app is added, and yes I added the secret key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems that were preventing AppCheck from working.

First, I spaced the fact that "firebase deploy" builds your cloud functions, but it does NOT build your flutter app, so code changes to my app were not being deployed.  I needed to run "flutter build web" first.

Second, in the Firebase console -> Authentication -> Settings -> Authorized Domains, there is a list of domains.  All those domains must be added to reCAPTCHA.  I had 3 out of 4.  The Firebase generated one I didn't add is probably used to send the requests used by AppCheck.

Once I addresses those two issues, AppCheck started working for all my cloud functions and real time database requests.  Hope this helps!

Comment: App Check is a nightmare, its not working for me, I checked all domains, site client id and secret key, and I have enforceAppCheck on my functions. Not sure what else to do..